# Deriving current density from charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics

Sorry for the naive question, but in Jackson's book in Electrodynamics, exercise 9.10, they give the charge density for the transition of hydrogen from 2p to 1s,

$$\rho=\frac{2e}{\sqrt{6}a_0^4}re^{-3r/2a_0}Y_{00}Y_{10}e^{-i\omega_0 t}$$

Immediatly after they give the current density as:

$$\vec{J}=\frac{-i\nu_0}{2}(\frac{\hat{r}}{2}+\frac{a_0}{z}\hat{r})\rho$$

However, I don't really understand how they derived the current from the charge density. I've tried using the continuity equation,

$$\nabla\cdot\vec{J}+\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$$

Or the fluid equation,

$$\vec{J}=\rho v$$

where $v$ is the velocity (not given in the statement).. However, neither of these give me the result, so I would like to know if there's another way to derive it.

Comment: Strange it did not work with the charge-current conservation equation. This is what I always use. So can you evaluate all the spherical harmonics, take the time derivative and show what you get for the divergence of the current density? i.e. $\boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{J}=???$.

Comment: Also note that $\langle 1s | \boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{J} | 2p\rangle =  \int d^3 r\, \psi_{1s} ^\dagger \boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{J} \psi_{2p}= - \int d^3 r \mathbf{J}. \boldsymbol{\nabla}\left(\psi_{1s} ^\dagger \psi_{2p}\right) =  \langle  \boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi_{1s} |.\mathbf{J}|2p\rangle - \langle 1s |\mathbf{J}.| \boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi_{2p}\rangle$. Not sure this is the way to go, but it could give you the matrix element of the current density if the wavefunctions transform nicely.